# How to remove a certain space in Javascript but not all spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, html-table

I'm trying to remove a few characters along with a white space. The string is like this:

```
<table id="myTable"><br/> <tbody><br/> <tr><br/> <td>1</td><br/> <td>1</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>1</td><br/> <td>1</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>1</td><br/> <td>1</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>2</td><br/> <td>2</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>2</td><br/> <td>2</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>2</td><br/> <td>2</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>3</td><br/> <td>3</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>3</td><br/> <td>3</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>3</td><br/> <td>3</td><br/> </tr><br/> </tbody> <br/></table>
```

I want to remove only the `<br/>` and the space after it. Then split it line-by-line with this code, since its an HTML `table` element.

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable").outerHTML
var linebyline = table2.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
```

And then with the for loop

```
var oneline = "", i = 0
for (lines in linebyline ){
    oneline += linebyline [lines].replace(/<br\/>\s/g,"")
}
```

I was expecting the removal of the `<br/>` and the white space but the output of `oneline` was :

```
<table id="myTable"> <tbody> <tr> <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr> <tr> <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr> <tr> <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr> <tr> <td>2</td> <td>2</td> </tr> <tr> <td>2</td> <td>2</td> </tr> <tr> <td>2</td> <td>2</td> </tr> <tr> <td>3</td> <td>3</td> </tr> <tr> <td>3</td> <td>3</td> </tr> <tr> <td>3</td> <td>3</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>
```

The white space still exists. How to remove all the substrings with `<br/>` and the space after it?

Comment: Use `.replace(/<br\/>\s+/g,"")` (mind the plus sign). Additionally it is `whitespace`.

Comment: i try it it give the same results

Comment: Is not a good idea to use regex to processing HTML. You can remove the `<br/>`s using something like this `Array.from(document.getElementById("myTable").querySelectorAll("br")).forEach(br => br.remove())`

Comment: @Titus you should post that as answer mate

Comment: @CodeManiac Agreed.

Comment: @CodeManiac I will have done that but that approach doesn't remove the spaces (even though I don't think that is necessary).

Comment: i need to remove the spaces because i need it as string not as element

Comment: @Titus: Guys, the space *after* `<br/>`, that's exactly the reason why I proposed a regex here.

Comment: your answers are all rights but i need the string to be like this  `<table id="myTable"><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>1</td>` for a good reason

Comment: I am interested to know how where your HTML has come from? It's odd that it has the `<br/>` outside of the table elements like this. Some sort of third party you are dealing with?

Comment: Is the HTML already rendered to the page or can you play with it before hand? e.g. is it a string or do we need to manipulate the DOM here?

Comment: the html come from json data that i converted to html table, originally im trying to add collapse button above each cells that have the same numbers,i want when click the all common data in cells show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach using DOM manipulation:

```js
const table = document.querySelector("#myTable");

Array.from(table.querySelectorAll("br")).forEach(br => br.remove())

let n;
const textNodes = [];
const walk = document.createTreeWalker(table, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);

while (n = walk.nextNode()) {
  textNodes.push(n);
}

textNodes.forEach(n => {
  if (!n.textContent.trim().length) {
    n.remove()
  }
})


console.log(table.outerHTML)
```

```html
<table id="myTable"><br/> <tbody><br/> <tr><br/> <td>1</td><br/> <td>1</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>1</td><br/> <td>1</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>1</td><br/> <td>1</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>2</td><br/> <td>2</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>2</td><br/> <td>2</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>2</td><br/> <td>2</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>3</td><br/> <td>3</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>3</td><br/> <td>3</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>3</td><br/> <td>3</td><br/> </tr><br/> </tbody> <br/></table>
```

It seems the browser removes the `<br />` elements itself, at least Chrome does.

If instead of the `<table>` element being in the DOM you have just a string, you could still use this solution by parsing the string with a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Answer (score 1):

You need a quantifier (e.g. `+` or `*`):

```js
let html = `<table id="myTable"><br/> <tbody><br/> <tr><br/> <td>1</td><br/> <td>1</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>1</td><br/> <td>1</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>1</td><br/> <td>1</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>2</td><br/> <td>2</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>2</td><br/> <td>2</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>2</td><br/> <td>2</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>3</td><br/> <td>3</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>3</td><br/> <td>3</td><br/> </tr><br/> <tr><br/> <td>3</td><br/> <td>3</td><br/> </tr><br/> </tbody> <br/></table>`

html = html.replace(/<br\/>\s*/g, "")
console.log(html)
```

Comment: @AndrewL64: Thanks. `SO` generally dislikes working with regular expressions on `HTML` - often with a good reason. In this particular example I think it is ok, though.

Comment: I usually avoid regex because I am not that fluent with it (mainly due to avoiding it as much as I can through the years lol). I really should start learning and working with it though considering how much faster it is than most alternative routes (in most cases).